# OpenCV and 14/42 bit

Tags: c++, opencv, bit-depth

Currently I am working on a project where i'm taking images from a camera.
Issue is though, it gives either 14 or 42 bit 3 channel images (depending on settings).

What I am trying to figure out, but can not really find anything about is can i somehow convert the incoming 14 or 42 bit image to a format that is usable for OpenCV?

It would even be enough if I managed to get it to the CV_8U, 3 settings in this case.

Anyone that can give me any insight on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get your data into your program? Is it saved in files and do you read them with `cv::imread()`? What's the `Mat::type()` then?

The best seems to scale the 14-bit data to 16-bit by simply multipling it with 4. So you can store it in an CV_16U Mat.

Comment: It's obtained directly from a camera, I first calculate how many bytes i need to allocate to obtain the screen, then iwrite the screen (image) to an unsigned short*, that is what i try to convert to a Mat using Mat(). It's pretty similair to how I implemented a way to use libtiff for multi-page tiffs to use a specific directory, but it didn't have the 14/42bit issue